# Laravel ORM nested relationships with constraints

Tags: laravel-4, nested, relationships

I'm wondering how to perform a nested relationship query with constraints in Laravel 4.1.

Here is a reference query which works:

```
$users = User::with("careers.specialty.faculty.university")->get();
```

As you can see, there are several nested models (with various relation types).

I would like to load an optional constraint to one or several models, for instance a faculty name...

What would be the best (and simplest) way to achieve this?

Here is what I tried so far, but it seems that the constraints are not taken into account (all users are returned).

```
    $users = User::with([
        'careers'=> function($query)use($levelInput){
                if ($levelInput ==""){
                    $query->get();
                }else{
                    $query->where('level','=',$levelInput)->get();
                }
            },
        'careers.specialty'=> function($query)use($specialtyInput){
                if ($specialtyInput ==""){
                    $query->get();
                }else{
                    $query->where('name','like','%'.$specialtyInput.'%')->get();
                }
            },
        'careers.specialty.faculty'=> function($query)use($facultyInput){
                if ($facultyInput ==""){
                    $query->get();
                }else{
                    $query->where('name','like','%'.$facultyInput.'%')->get();
                }
            },
        'careers.specialty.faculty.university'=> function($query)use($universityInput){
                if ($universityInput ==""){
                    $query->get();
                }else{
                    $query->where('name','like','%'.$universityInput.'%')->get();
                }
            }
        ])->get();
```

---

EDIT : Here is a solution, thanks to Maksym Cierzniak's accepted answer:

```
$users = User::whereHas('promos',function($q)use($levelInput,$specialtyInput,$facultyInput,$universityInput){
        $q->where('level','like','%'.$levelInput.'%')->whereHas('specialty',function($q)use($specialtyInput,$facultyInput,$universityInput){
            $q->where('name','like','%'.$specialtyInput.'%')->whereHas('faculty',function($q)use($facultyInput,$universityInput){
                $q->where('name','like','%'.$facultyInput.'%')->whereHas('universities',function($q)use($universityInput){
                    $q->where('name','like','%'.$universityInput.'%');
                });
            });
        });
    })->get();
```

Well, this code looks really ugly. But it works, and if you have a better option, feel free to share it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `with` works that way so relations are eagerly loaded to the base model you are looking for. In this case you will always get all `User` records then Laravel will try to fetch relationships for all of them. If you'd like to load all users which relations have some kind of constraint you should try `whereHas` method. This way if you for example call

```
$posts = Blog::whereHas('comments', function($query){
   $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->get();
```

This way you will only get the `Blog` which have some comments with `content` like foo. I hope this is what you are looking for.